# What are differences creating viewmodels way?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm using viewModel in my project already. But ı know ı can initalize viewmodel with many ways. Do you know what are the differences between these ways?

- viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelClass::class.java)
- viewModel = ViewModelClass()
- viewModel : ViewModelClass : by viewModels()
- viewModel : ViewModelClass by ViewModelse{
  ViewModelFactory(this,Reposityory(),intent
  }

What are the technical differences?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html by is delegation in kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using

- `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelClass::class.java)` your are creating an instance of `ViewModelClass` scoped to this Fragment/activity and whenever the activity gets recreated **same** instance of the viewmodel is assigned rather than a new instance
- `viewModel = ViewModelClass()` though it seems to be correct, it isn't . Whenever the activity gets recreated, **new** instance of viewmodel is assigned. **Dont try** to create an instance of ViewModel by directly calling its constructor, instead let the `ViewModelProvider` do the job.
- `viewModel: ViewModelClass by viewModels()` courtesy of [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment) here you [delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) the creation of ViewModel . Its similar to

```
  val viewModel by lazy{
     ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
  }
```

- `viewModel : ViewModelClass by ViewModels{ ViewModelFactory(this,Reposityory(),intent)}` its similar to

```
val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactory(this,Reposityory(),intent)).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```